# How to get the ajax url successful function value to use globally from this -> $('.demo').html(html);

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I get the some of information to the ajax url successfully and the value will display in

tag also like this my p tag

This is my Ajax Code:

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "joins.php", //"join.php"
            dataType:"html",
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
                $('.demo').html(html);
            } });
```

This Out put i will came.

TATA Wiron TW02
     Quantity= 33 Kgs
     Total Price = 4125

    Tata Wiron Aayush
    Quantity= 33 Kgs
    Total Price = 3630

but my problem is

tag content will passed another page to send the details for users you have selected this items how can i pass the values

i will try local Storage option also not working any idea about that

Comment: you can use `local storage` to store data across the pages.

Comment: Just send in `data`

Comment: local storage also try data will not save local storage@Vishalmodi

Comment: where i can send data i have already used the data bit no use how@Andreas

Comment: What do you mean by another page? Another page that is currently in a separate tab?

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: another page means i will send the output values from p tag where i can get the results . Then that result  can send to sendsms.php page

Comment: can u please write how to send the data @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in [local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Here is an example:

```
localStorage.setItem('keyname', 'value'); // set the key
```

and then

```
localStorage.getItem('keyname'); // get the key
```

Alternatively, you can use [location.hash](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/apis/location/hash/), you can pass a parameter through the url and grab it at the destination page, like this:

```
https://url#foo
```

and then `window.location.hash` will return `foo`

Most likely, you will pick  the hash option if you are passing a single parameter only and not an object.

Comment: here how can i setItems plz explain the above code to how to set

Comment: @TonyNagendraKumar just click on the local storage link and read.

Comment: i am new for this concept i am not able to understand that concept